# How can I reserve to see sunrise at Haleakalā, if the federal gov't shutdown is hindering online reservations?

Tags: usa, event-based-effects, maui

I know that sunsets don't require reservations, but my grandparents still fancy seeing sunrise.

1. How can one book online, if the [online reservation system](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/130332/13759) isn't updated?
2. If not, then how to book? By telephone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [popup banner on recreation.gov](https://www.recreation.gov/ticket/facility/253731) regarding the shutdown:

> ## Lapse in Funding for the Federal Government
>
> #### The lapse in funding for the Federal government may impact your reservation and travel plans.
>
> - Be aware that if you have an existing reservation during this lapse of funding period, and the location is not fully staffed, your reservation may not be honored.
> - Many locations are open. These may include locations operated by concessionaires, all Army Corps of Engineer Projects, and Alaska Cabins. We recommend you call the local facility number listed on the facility page herein.
> - If you do make a reservation for the near future and the lapse in funding is not resolved by your arrival date, your reservation may not be honored or others may have occupied your site. Please consider this when making new reservations. Please check with local facilities as they may be open for business and welcoming new reservations.
> - Inter-agency passes are not being sold at this time as we are unable to fulfill on-line orders during the shutdown. We apologize for this inconvenience.

Comment: Assume that all employees at Haleakalā fail to show up for work. Will the gates to Haleakalā (if any) be opened or closed by default?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal According to the [banner on the Haleakalā web site](https://www.nps.gov/hale/index.htm): "*Some national parks may remain accessible to visitors; however, access may change without notice.*" Your question cannot be answered definitively one way or the other. The only way to find out for sure is to show up on the day.